# wxpython, buscador para wx.listctrl

Tags: python, lista, arraylist, wxpython, wxwidgets

tengo una situacion que no estoy pudiendo resolver en mi proyecto. La cuestion es que estoy desarrollando un administrador de listas para reparaciones, tengo todo armado y de hecho funcionando, solo estoy rompiendome la cabeza tratando de armar un buscador interactivo que busque, valga la dedundancia, coincidencias del wx.searchctrl en la lista armada de wx.listctrl.
Lo que se me ocurrio para resolverlo momentaneamente es que al encontrar coincidencias pinte las mismas de un color determinado, aunque no es tan practico es lo que pude..
dejo el codigo

````
        search_text = self.buscador.GetValue().lower()
        
        for i in range(self.cajaL.GetItemCount()):
            item_text = self.cajaL.GetItemText(i).lower()
            if search_text and search_text in item_text:
                self.cajaL.SetItemBackgroundColour(i, wx.Colour(0, 0, 255))
                items_coincidentes.append(i)
            else:
                self.cajaL.SetItemBackgroundColour(i, wx.Colour(0, 0, 0))
                items_no_coincidentes.append(i)```

podrian orientarme a como hacer para que al poner claves en el buscador busque las coincidencias, borre los items no coincidentes y muestre en el wx.listctrl las coincidencias (Que tambien luego de borrar el string del searchctrl restaure la lista a como estaba)?. No me encontre con nada de informacion al respecto! Gracias a todos
###############
EDIT 27/9:
Logre convertir el codigo anterior en una funcion mas decente, ahora elimina todos los items no coincidentes y me imprime en el listctrl los que si son coincidentes.
Dejo la funcion editada :
```def buscarLista(self, e):
        search_text = self.buscador.GetValue().lower()
        
        item_data = []
        for row in range(self.cajaL.GetItemCount()):
            item_data.append([])
            for col in range(self.cajaL.GetColumnCount()):
                item_data[row].append(self.cajaL.GetItemText(row, col).lower())
        self.cajaL.DeleteAllItems()
        
        if search_text != 0:
            
            matching_rows = []

            for row in item_data:
                if any(search_text in cell for cell in row):
                    matching_rows.append(row)

            for row in matching_rows:
                index = self.cajaL.InsertItem(self.cajaL.GetItemCount(), row[0])
                for i, value in enumerate(row[1:], 1):
                    self.cajaL.SetItem(index, i, value)```
Estoy teniendo inconvenientes en lograr que me devuelva todos los items como estaban al borrar el contenido del searchctrl..
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo logre y quede super conforme,
Cree una función que guarde un archivo temporal antes de buscar, al escribir separa coincidencias y no coincidencias, las coincidencias las pone arriba y las ordena por orden de fecha, las no coincidencias las pone abajo de las coincidencias y las ordena también por orden de fecha. Una vez que borras el contenido del buscador se restaura el orden del archivo temporal

````
        search_text = self.buscador.GetValue().lower()
        item_data = []
        for row in range(self.cajaL.GetItemCount()):
            item_data.append([])
            for col in range(self.cajaL.GetColumnCount()):
                item_data[row].append(self.cajaL.GetItemText(row, col).lower())
        self.cajaL.DeleteAllItems()
        
        matching_rows = []
        unmatching_rows = []
        for row in item_data:
            if any(search_text in cell for cell in row):
                matching_rows.append(row)
            else:
                unmatching_rows.append(row)
        
        if matching_rows != 0:            
            self.archTemp = 1
            for row in matching_rows:
                capitalized_row = [word.capitalize() for word in row]
                index = self.cajaL.InsertItem(self.cajaL.GetItemCount(), capitalized_row[0])
                for i, value in enumerate(capitalized_row[1:], 1):
                    self.cajaL.SetItem(index, i, value)
            else:    
                if unmatching_rows != 0:
                    for row in unmatching_rows:
                        capitalized_row = [word.capitalize() for word in row]
                        index = self.cajaL.InsertItem(self.cajaL.GetItemCount(), capitalized_row[0])
                        for i, value, in enumerate(capitalized_row[1:], 1):
                            self.cajaL.SetItem(index, i, value)  
                        self.archTemp = None
        if len(search_text) == 0:
            self.abrirTemporal()```
````

Comment: Buenas, Hatxy, está permitido responderse a uno mismo, pero no hay una línea de código en tu respuesta. ¿Exactamente cómo has implementado todo eso y cómo se relacionado con el código que pusiste originalmente?

Comment: Hola Rubio, ahí hice la edición con la función completa, espero sirva el código para entender por donde fue el tema

Comment: por cierto los archivos que manejo son csv

Comment: Algo mejor. Puedes marcar esta respuesta como aceptada.